# Maxima and minima nth derivative reasoning

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I found a statement somewhere in my notes that if we have a higher order function and lets say we take the nth derivative of it. If n is odd and the result turns out to be any number except zero then we will not be able to tell whether the curve has a maxima or a minima at that point.why is it so?
What's the reason behind it?

Comment: Are you taking the n-th derivative and calculating it at a specific point?

Comment: But is it necessary that if we derive it odd no. Of times getting a non zero constant at the end. Then we will not be able to tell whether it's a maxima or a minima.

Comment: In using this at a point $c,$ I believe all the lower derivatives have to vanish at $c$ before the $n$th derivative at $c$ can give any information.